Insert new line between a text file from another text file using python
Here's a script that inserts data after a line.it works when data is given directly. But i want it to take data from a text file and then insert that data.
can someone tell me where i went wrong and how to correct that or do this in a better manner with explanation( I'm new to python, and i have to apply this method on other files as well).
Thanks
I tried
#new line to be inserted in sample.txt
with open("sample.txt", "r") as f:
    contents = f.readlines()
#take data to be inserted from calinks.txt
with open("calinks.txt", "r") as g:
    contentsg = [ ]
    contentsg = g.readlines()
    
contents.insert(2, contentsg)

with open("sample.txt", "w") as f:
    contents = "".join(contents)
    f.write(contents)   

Error:
    contents = "".join(contents)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, list found

The post to which you linked is nowhere related to what I want,  or maybe I'm not able to understand.
please give me a working method or don't mark this post as duplicate, I'm sure someone else will fulfill my requirements.

What's the point of doing contentsg = [] before you overwrite it with g.readlines()?

was just trying to make this code work, but it didnt

Do you understand that insert is creating a nested list? ["file1-line1", "file1-line2", ["file2-line1", "file2-line2", ...], "file1-line3", "file1-line4", ...]? That's why you're getting the error.

you need to splice the lines of file 2 into file 1, not nest them.

i don't understand this.

how to splice , and how should I not nest.

Don't you see "This question already has answers here:" at the top?
